# Was Einstein's General Theory of Relativity wrong?

Tags: general-relativity, refraction, popular-science

> Albert Einstein Failed in Three Classical Tests
>
> At his theory on general relativity, Einstein concluded that the light just as other material objects, moved in curve if gravity field of an object was massive.
>
> Albert Einstein proposed three tests of general relativity, subsequently called the classical tests of general relativity, in 1916:
>
> 1. the perihelion precession of Mercury’s orbit
> 2. the deflection of light by the Sun
> 3. the gravitational redshift of light
>
> He also mentioned with comments:
>
> “….If a single one of the conclusions drawn from it proves wrong, it must be given up; to modify it without destroying the whole structure seems to be impossible.”

and [Bending of Light Near a Star and Gravitational Red/Blue Shift :
Alternative Explanation Based on Refraction of Light](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0409124)

> The new alternative explanation is based on refraction phenomenon of optics. It predicts that as the ray passes through/near the star’s atmospheric medium, it bends due to refraction phenomenon towards star core, like a ray bends while passing through a prism or water drop.

Recently I was reading some answers about the validity of the Theory of Relativity, and I came across a post on mediam. I would like to know the veracity of these claims

Comment: General Relativity successfully predicts the outcomes of the three classic tests you list, as well as [many others](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0510072). To *replace* GR, an alternative theory must (a) reproduce *all* of the successes of GR (ideally using fewer assumptions), and (b) predict something *new* that GR does not predict, which is experimentally verified. No theory to date has achieved this.

Comment: There are countless web sites claiming that Einstein is wrong. If we had to review every one of them it would swamp the site. If someone is going to make an extraordinary claim the onus is upon them to provide extraordinary evidence, and given the experimental evidence supporting GR claiming it's wrong is indeed and extraordinary claim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The claim is incorrect. General relativity passes all of those tests and many more. In particular, many of the measurements of the deflection of light near the sun are made using VLBI with radio telescopes at distances that are far beyond the solar atmosphere and thus well beyond the range where refraction is even a possible explanation.